# select case when in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables

First tabel name is "consumer"

| id_consumer | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Roy |
| 2 | Dori |
| 3 | Rico |

Second tabel name is "consumer_address"

| id_consumer | address | status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Street Avenue | 1 |
| 1 | Park Hill | 0 |
| 2 | Highwalk Street | 1 |
| 2 | Albion Place | 0 |

Condition

1. name from tabel "consumer"
2. address from "consumer_address" , but i want to get only 1 address when consumer_address.status = 1
3. When Consumer not have data in tabel "consumer_address", field is NULL

The Final Tabel Like this

| id_consumer | name | address | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Roy | Street Avenue | 1 |
| 2 | Dori | Highwalk Street | 1 |
| 3 | Rico | NULL | NULL |

i have query, but its not work
this is my query

```
SELECT 
id_consumer, 
name,
CASE WHEN (`consumer_address`.`status` = 1)  THEN `consumer_address`.`address` ELSE NULL END as "Address",
CASE WHEN (`consumer_address`.`status` = 1)  THEN `consumer_address`.`status` ELSE NULL END as "Status"
FROM consumer
JOIN consumer_address ON consumer_address.id_consumer = consumer.id_consumer
```

Thanks

Comment: Does customer can have multiple addresses with. status 1?

Comment: no, consumer only can have 1 address with status 1

Answer (score 1):

Very simple solution:

```
SELECT 
    `id_consumer`, 
    `name`,
    `consumer_address`.`address`,
    `consumer_address`.`status`
FROM consumer
LEFT JOIN consumer_address ON 
    `consumer_address`.`id_consumer` = `consumer`.`id_consumer` AND
    `consumer_address`.`status` = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using CASE WHEN just include the status in the JOIN.

Additionally, to keep consumer 3, you need a LEFT JOIN.

```
SELECT 
    id_consumer, 
    name,
    `consumer_address`.`address`,
    `consumer_address`.`status`
FROM
    consumer
LEFT JOIN
    consumer_address
        ON  consumer_address.id_consumer = consumer.id_consumer
        AND consumer_address.status = 1
```